# fetching data from mysql databases

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone is there any possibly to fetch data from mysql databases in javascript . For example i have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>


        <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>

        <!-- 1a) Optional: add a theme file -->
        <!--
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/themes/gray.js"></script>
        -->

        <!-- 1b) Optional: the exporting module -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>


        <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
        <script type="text/javascript">


            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });

            var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                        marginRight: 10,
                        events: {
                            load: function() {

                                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                                var series = this.series[0];
                                setInterval(function() {
                                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                        y = Math.random();
                                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                                }, 500);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Live random data'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        tickPixelInterval: 150
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Value'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+ 
                                Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Random data',
                        data: (function() {
                            // generate an array of random data
                            var data = [],
                                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                                i;

                            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                                data.push({
                                    x: time + i * 1000,
                                    y: Math.random()
                                });
                            }
                            return data;
                        })()
                    }]
                });


            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
```

from this code

```
   data: (function() {
                            // generate an array of random data
                            var data = [],
                                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                                i;

                            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                                data.push({
                                    x: time + i * 1000,
                                    y: Math.random()
                                });
                            }
                            return data;
```

instead of random no i want to fetch from the database . please guide

Comment: Is it running on PHP in the backend?

Comment: @webarto sorry for that , but i am wondering might be there are some methods

Comment: @umar, you can make JSON with PHP (from database) and then fetch and manipulate it with Javascript. But directly, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect to a MySQL database from traditional Javascript. You'll have to do that server-side, such as in PHP.

There are some in-between solutions, such as Jaxer, (A tutorial [here](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/javascript-mysql-with-jaxer/).), but this would probably be a bit over your head.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's (fortunately) no express-way from JavaScript to MySQL. You'd have to make requests against some custom HTTP-based service (written in whatever programming language) that then accesses MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Make an AJAX request to the PHP script (using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or whichever way you prefer), and get the PHP script to give you back JSON data of the row using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)